# Transformation of normal random vector from $ℝ^2$ to $ℝ^3$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

$$X=(X_1,X_2)$$ $$E(X_1)=1,\ E(X_2)=2$$

$$
C^2_X =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\
-1&2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

X is normal random vector, which means it is a bivariate normal random variable. In other words, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are jointly normal.

If we were to use a function $g:ℝ^2 \rightarrow ℝ^3: g(X) = (X_1+X_2, X_1-X_2,2X_2)=XB,$

$$where \ \ B=  \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
1&-1&2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

then,
$$E(g(X))=  \begin{bmatrix}
3&-1&4\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

and,

$$
C^2_{g(X)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&2\\
-1&5&-6\\
-1&-6&8\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

now, $$det(C^2_{g(X)})=|C^2_{g(X)}|= 0$$

The question asks to find distribution of Z. My friend said something about transformation of random variable from $ℝ^2$ to $ℝ^3$ doesn't have a density because it doesn't span $ℝ^3$. How does one explain why the density function of g(X) doesn't exist? Would one be able to explain this using the fact the determinant is $0$? What is the distribution of g(X)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $B$ transforms onto a plane. (From a plane to a plane.) $Z$'s distribution is concentrated in that plane. So there is no density wrt the $R^3$ Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment! Could you please tell me in a bit more detail about how B transforms on to a plane? My knowledge on spaces is a a bit limiting. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much abut your problem. I know only that $B$ transforms the $xy$ plane onto another plane.

Comment: So how do we know the transform is a plane?

Comment: $\{(x',y',z')\mid x'=x+y, y'=x-y, z'=2x; \  x,y,z\in R^3
\}$ is a plane: $Ax'+By'+C'z'=0$ if $A=1, B=1, C=-1$. Indeed, $$x+y+x-y-2x=0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now.

Comment: In general you cannot increase the "degree of freedom" by transformation.

Comment: If the question asks to find the distribution of Z, simply answering that Z is always in a plane hence that Z has no PDF, should not suffice. Distributions with no PDF exist and this one can be described precisely.